# How does Typescript infer Generics and why does it not work in one case?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is there a Typescript error with `f2(f1)`? For me it seems that f2, f3 and f4 have the same types. It's just declared different. Where is the difference of f4 to f2 or f3?

I've got the following example:

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Code:

```
interface FullType {
  id: string;
  order_no: number;
}

interface OrderType {
  [key: string]: any;
  order_no: number;
}

const f1 = (d1: FullType): Promise<FullType> => {
  return new Promise(() => {
    return d1;
  });
};

function f2<Type extends OrderType, Fn extends (t: Type) => Promise<Type>>(
  f: Fn,
): void {
  //
}

function f3<Type extends OrderType>(f: (t: Type) => Promise<Type>): void {
  //
}

function f4<Type1 extends Type2, Type2 extends OrderType>(
  f: (item: Type1) => Promise<Type1>,
): void {
  //
}

f2(f1); // why is here a warning
f3(f1);
f4(f1);
```

Comment: True, I've edited it. However, that doesn't change the question.

Comment: Generic constraints do not serve as inference sites for other type parameters; support for this was suggested in [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) but was never implemented. So there's no inference site for `Type` at all in `f2`, and it falls back to the constraint `OrderType`, and then it's all over because now `Fn` is constrained to `(t: OrderType)=>Promise<OrderType>`.  `f4` only works because the failure of `Type2` inference harmlessly falls back to `OrderType` so it's equivalent to `f3`. Generally speaking you don't want too many type params.

Comment: If that explains things to you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, generics usually work just fine, however when you start using already extended generic types to define new generic types that will also be extended - this is where the trouble occurs. In general, **Generic Constraints** (e.g. `<T>`) in TypeScript are not considered as types that can be inferred further, meaning that whilst extending an extended type like you have in `f4` is harmless, extending a newly defined type that also uses generics is problematic:

`f4` is perfectly fine:

`<Type1 extends Type2, Type2 extends OrderType>`

`f3` is also fine as it is not extending the type to define the callback but is instead creating directly:

`f: (t: Type) => Promise<Type>`

`f2` is where the problem begins to occur as the parameter type is using an extended generic type that also uses extended values. This causes the type to default itself back to `OrderType` and because `FullType` does not directly equal `OrderType` you are observing that error:

`Fn extends (t: Type) => Promise<Type>`

This can be further illustrated by defining this in a separate type:

```
type CustomCallback<T> = (t: T) => Promise<T>;

// This will work just fine
function f2<Type extends OrderType>(f: CustomCallback<Type>): void {
  //
}

// this will not
function f2<Type extends OrderType, paramType extends CustomCallback<Type>>(f: paramType): void {
  //
}
```

Here is the Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcA2mAqBPABxQG8AoZZYAEwC5kBnMKUAcwG5zkB7KK6AfRBc6IdAFsARtA4BfUqVCRYiFAHle0fEWRkKAbQDWEPHUbMQLALp04IPBwo8%20UQcOSjJ00nNIIuIRmQYAEZkAF5kAAoqYLoMbC0IAEo6AAUoLjFgeggAHnjcQggAPnDS3WQoCDB0KBB3CAB3ZHTM7IhIyKSynU4KKpq65BiHZBkk2Q5SGHQQBDBgfyCAJlzE5AgAD0gQKnpkdWdEgBo0eq2dvaiwOkTusNLWrJy1ouLiyM4YOJBj0hTkAA3LjUXoUAD04O88hmcwWSxgAGZXtoLhBdvtDpo3pFvtdbkV7o8Ms88oligDgaCKpDodNZvNFvUYAAWFEQUJojHIRLLU68jbbdFXLFQcmfCh4yLASBiAlEYJElok9rs4LFP6UkFUMHIWk%20GDLXGKth68HIRoACzwlH2lugKDgFrgdVY00Rxom0xZnqmYCKyAAwuhGJlA3BsBJEAY1qUIpEbjylU9VThilNYYyEQBWdmCy6YjRinF44OhsThyPR9kUuhUnU0qEGhnw5kANjzXJFRZOyAILrgYnWXf2ZbAYYjmCjCBj5I%20eP7UEHdzr2t1%20ph2d90zbvqAA).

I must additionally mention that the keyword `extends` extracts all of the known properties from a type and allows other values to be used due to the index signature `[key: string]: any;` property defined in `OrderType`, hence this is the reason why no errors are being displayed for `f3` and `f4`. However if you used a direct type in any one of them you will start to see a warning because `FullType` does not equal `OrderType`.

```
function f3(f: (t: OrderType) => Promise<OrderType>): void {
  //
}

f3(f1); // warning
```

To sum it all up, as a general rule, try to avoid extending generic types that are already using extended variables.

Comment: Do you have references in the specs or docs for this?

Comment: This is not defined in the official documentation. There are quite a few bugs for generic constraints in TypeScript, many of which can be found in the ***issues*** tab of the TypeScript github repo. I can see @jcalz has provided the correct reference for this issue (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) . You can give him an upvote.